# Error: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: database, errors

My php error_log keep showing this message,

> WordPress database error Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_value' in 'order clause' for query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND 0 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 made ​​by require ('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts

I never change something in my database.

Anyone knows something bout this or ever have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't be caused by a change in the database. What the error refers to is this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.id
FROM   wp_posts
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND 0
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id
ORDER  BY wp_postmeta.meta_value + 0 DESC,
          wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT  0, 10
```

Your code only includes data from the `wp_posts` table (second line above) but is trying to `ORDER BY` data from the `wp_postmeta` table (sixth line). You can't do that. I doubt this is coming from WordPress Core, so a plugin or your theme is hooking a callback into one of the `WP_Query` hooks-- my guess is the `posts_orderby` filter. Something about that filter is broken and it is adding that `wp_postmeta.meta_value` bit indiscriminantly.

Comment: so, what do you suggest i do? How i know which plugin that causing this problem? I'm really new with this.

Comment: Disable your plugins one by one and see when the problem stops, then read the plugin code. Same with the theme-- switch themes, see if it stops.